# Pyramid minimum sum path 2D ArrayList IndexOutOfBounds

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to calculate a pyramid's minimum bottom-up path sum. I am reading inputs from a text file.

My Text File example:

```
5
6
6 5
3 5 8
3 9 2 1
4 7 9 2 7
```

The first row informs the program about size of pyramid and the others are assembling the pyramid. (In this example the size is 5).

This is my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    if(args.length > 0) {   
        File file1 = new File(args[0]);
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(file1); // The Scanner that is going to read file1.
        int pyramidSize = scanner1.nextInt();
        scanner1.next();
        System.out.println("Pyramid Size = " + pyramidSize);
        ArrayList<ArrayList <Integer>> solution1List = new ArrayList<ArrayList <Integer>>(pyramidSize);
        // Reads all integers to an array list.

        while(scanner1.hasNext()) {
            int row = 1;

            if(scanner1.hasNextInt()) {    
                int temporaryForSolution1Integer = scanner1.nextInt();
                solution1List.get(row).add(temporaryForSolution1Integer);
            }
            else {
                scanner1.next();
                row++;
            }


            scanner1.close(); // Closed the scanner in order to prevent resource leak.
        }

         System.out.println("The minimum sum path is = " + minimumSumPath(solution1List));
```

This is the method that I am using to calculate the minimum path:

```
public static int minimumSumPath(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> triangle) {

    if (triangle.size() == 0)
        return 0;
    int size = triangle.size();
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    int[] sum = new int[size];
    sum[0] = triangle.get(0).get(0);
    for(int current = 1; current <= size - 1; current++){
        int next_size = triangle.get(current).size();
        // it has to start with the end of the array
        // because the further one need the clean sum 
        // value than the newer one.
        for(int next = next_size - 1; next >= 0; next--) {
            if (next == 0) {
                sum[0] = sum[0] + triangle.get(current).get(next);
            } else if (next == (next_size - 1)) { // Reaches to the rightmost element of that iteration
                sum[next] = sum[next-1] + triangle.get(current).get(next);
            } else { // Provides sum[next] to be the minimal sum that can come there
                sum[next] = Math.min(sum[next-1], sum[next]) + triangle.get(current).get(next);
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if(sum[i] < min){
           min = sum[i];
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

Currently I am encountering with an error like:

```
PS C:\Users\berku\Desktop\BERKSOL> javac .\berkSol.java
PS C:\Users\berku\Desktop\BERKSOL> java berkSol input1.txt input2.txt
Pyramid Size = 5
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at berkSol.main(berkSol.java:23)
```

I think my method for the calculation is correct.

If someone could please help me with this error I would be really glad to him/her.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`solution1List.get(row).add(temporaryForSolution1Integer);` there is no element at that index.

You create a 2 dimensional list as
`ArrayList<ArrayList <Integer>> solution1List = new ArrayList<ArrayList <Integer>>(pyramidSize);`, but you never add actual `List` elements to it.

Before you can do `solution1List.get(0);` you have to do `solution1List.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());`

---

Note that `Lists` as well as `Arrays` are 0-based. this means that the first element is actually accessed with 0 and not with 1

Comment: I  tried with index  zero too. I am Having the same error with Index: 0, Size: 0. I will try your solution tough thanks.

Comment: @BerkUtkuYenisey as said, you first have to add a `new List` to that index. `ArrayList<ArrayList <Integer>>` doesn't initialize all the sublists, because you can have infinite and that would instantly crash your program

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice. I have fixed several errors with my code and now my code is working.